# Roku video playback fails in published app, works fine on dev

Tags: roku

I'm facing a strange problem, my app which is essentially simple video player. Works perfectly fine when its a dev app side loaded via eclipse plugin. However when I package and publish it on Roku and then use it , it behaves strangely. First screen gets loaded fine the one which actually plays video shows up plays a frame or two and closes abruptly.

Does anyone know if roku package and publish thingys might be doing some rewrites that is making my app misbehave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it does not touch the package once it had been zip-ed and sign-ed.

Try doing the upload directly with browser at port 80 of the player, as described in the documentation. The eclipse plugin is just a crutch, it cannot do anything that can't be done with a browser/telnet/curl at the box.

Also make sure you are testing in the very same conditions - on the same player, both the (private) channel from Roku servers and the "side-loaded" version.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nas for detailed reply. Apparently. there was an error condition in my app which wasn't handled well, the dev [side-loaded] app somehow resumed execution even after the run-time error. Prod app however used to crash right-away. I mistook the errors on the console for verbose logging and never noticed the error in my dev testing.